# Run a macro/VBA every 5 seconds

Tags: excel, vba

On an excel worksheet I have created several SQL Queries using Microsoft Power Query,
These queries should be refreshed every 5 seconds so new information is retrieved from a SQ database.

To Refresh , I go to the Data Tab in Excel and hit the Refresh All button which refreshes all workbooks.This works good

I want to automate this request every 5 seconds
Ideally,A macro should run the command Ctrl+Alt+F5 every 5 seconds in the background.

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ThisWorkbook Module*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call StartTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call StopTimer
End Sub
```

*General Module*

```
Option Explicit
Dim RunTime

Sub StartTimer()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    RunTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:15")
    Application.OnTime RunTime, "RefreshTime"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
'  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime RunTime, "RefreshTime", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub RefreshTime()
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    StartTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped! I found my answer in Om3r's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add an [Application.OnTime method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx) to the end of a macro that reruns itself in 5 seconds.

```
Option Explicit

Public bWORKING As Boolean
Public bKEEPWORKING As Boolean

Sub deja_vu()
    'never let it run on top of itself
    If bWORKING Then Exit Sub
    bWORKING = True

    'do something here; refresh connections or whatever

    Debug.Print Now 'just to show it did something

    If bKEEPWORKING Then _
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5), "deja_vu"
    bWORKING = False
End Sub
```

Assign `bKEEPWORKING` a value of True and run the Deja_vu sub procedure. It will keep running until you set `bKEEPWORKING`  to False. Occasionally, I might skip the `bKEEPWORKING` and have it look up a value on a specific worksheet cell. If the value is `0` then the procedure does not reschedule itself.